# What characters in my printed boot scroll are artifacts?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, special-characters

I am a tech writer and I need to include a boot dump in a document.  The dump the engineers gave me has some "bad characters" that I need to delete.  What form does a "bad character" take? There are lines that look like:
14;1h 0m2J0m2Jm2J1

Is any line with number followed by a semi colon an artifact?

Answer (score 1):

That stuff you show looks like parts of ESC-sequences. Do you have the original file? Then you could filter that stuff out, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) is a description of the ANSI escape sequences. Get your friendly geek write you a `sed(1)` script to filter them out (if on Unix/Linux; there should be similar search&replace tools for other systems).